# Rest calls to search API's suddenly stopped working, but they work in the graph explorer

Tags: rest, search, facebook-opengraph

Earlier today was successfully getting data making rest calls to the URL below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=id&q=res&type=event&access_token="my_auth_token"
```

Now when I try to make the call using curl or just pasting it into a browser I get and empty array. But when I paste the end of the same URL into the graph explorer tool I get an array with data. Any idea as to what's happening?

Comment: same here. it just stopped working like 1 hour ago

Comment: It started up again today. This time it works in the browser and explorer but not via curl.

Comment: Just tried it from a remote server and it worked. Still not working from my local server.